# Spring isn't resolving the appropriate constructor

Tags: java, spring, constructor-injection

Gratitude: Thanks for your support.

Problem Description:

1. I am facing an exception while trying to run the below code. Don't even have a clue.
2. How to write the xml definition to initiate Dependent class using @Autowired Constructor with int parameter.

ExceptionMessage:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'dependent' defined in class path 
 resource [simple-context.xml]: 
Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments 
 for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
```

filename: spring-context.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.learning.spring.constinjection" />

   <bean id="dependency" class="com.learning.spring.constinjection.Dependency"></bean>

   <bean id="dependent" class="com.learning.spring.constinjection.Dependent">
        <constructor-arg ref="dependency" name="dpcy" />
        <constructor-arg name="mesg" value="Hi this is a test mesg" />
   </bean> 

   <bean id="dependent2" class="com.learning.spring.constinjection.Dependent" 
        c:mesg="Hi, this is another test mesg" /> 


 </beans>
```

filename: Dependent.java

```
public class Dependent {

    Dependency dpcy;

    Dependent(Dependency dpcy, String mesg){
      this.dpcy = dpcy;
      System.out.println("Message is: " + mesg);
    }

    Dependent(String mesg){
      System.out.println("Only Message is: " + mesg);
    }

    @Autowired
    Dependent(Integer ticketno){
      System.out.println("Ticket no is: " + ticketno);
    }

}
```

filename: Dependency.java

```
public class Dependency {

  Dependency(){
      System.out.println("Dependency loaded successfully");
  }

}
```

filename: ConstructorInjectionApp

```
public class ConstructorInjectionApp {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

        GenericXmlApplicationContext gen = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
        gen.load("classpath:simplespringconstinjection.xml");
        gen.refresh();
        Dependent d = (Dependent) gen.getBean("dependent");
        Dependent d2 = (Dependent) gen.getBean("dependent2");   
}
}
```

Comment: Do you *need* that `@Autowired` annotation on the `Dependent` constructor? It's generally confusing to mix autowired annotations with xml/java definitions.

Comment: Ya its confusing, but, I am just learning springs. So I thought I should learn  the things first and then go for best practices.

Comment: may I know the reason for downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing this:

```
<bean id="dependent" class="com.learning.spring.constinjection.Dependent">
        <constructor-arg ref="dependency" name="dpcy" />
        <constructor-arg name="mesg" value="Hi this is a test mesg" />
   </bean>
```

to this:

```
<bean id="dependent" class="com.learning.spring.constinjection.Dependent" 
        c:dpcy-ref="dependency" c:mesg="Hi, this is another test mesg" />
```

I was able to get the `ApplicationContext` to properly initialize with no errors.

See [this Spring doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-c-namespace) for information on the "c" namespace.

There is still an issue with the constructor with the @Autowired annotation.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis thank you for the pointers. I was unfamiliar with the "c" namespace. I also did a sloppy job on my original response.